# Why won't the navigation button show when I add the title to my viewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, navigation

All I'm getting when I add the Navigation Bar is the bar and the title, so when I add the Navigation Item it just won't show. 
[image]

Comment: Have you added this viewcontroller to a navigation stack? In AppDelegate or something?

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationBar` displays a back button on the left and a title in the center,but it will be visible if your navigation controller stack contains more then one view controllers. Because there is no way of back button on navigationbar if there is only one viewcontroller in stack.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I have three view controllers, it won't show.. any solutions?

Comment: Are you using Navigationcontroller or viewcontroller ?

Comment: Then you should use UIToolbar instead of it and then add UIBarButtonItem to it. and you can add UIBarbuttonItem to navigationbar too.